# Use many beans from the same class, different scopes

Tags: jsf, managed-bean

I want to use a ManagedBean class, Users.java, to create 2 bean instances with different scopes. I tried to do this in 2 ways:

1.
Use ManagedBean and SessionScope annotations for Users (this creates a "users" with a session scope), and declare in faces-config.xml another MenagedBean from User, with request scope.

```
@ManagedBean
@Component
@SessionScoped
public class Users implements Serializable {...}
```

Note: "Component" is from Spring framework, this can be ignored for the moment.

In faces-config.xml:

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>newUser</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>ro.telacad.model.Users</managed-bean-class>   
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

In login page I use "#{users.}" inside . For this case, the login works fine (is made with Spring Security). I created also a "Sign up" page, and there, I need the "Users" bean with request scope to create a new user in database, "#{newUser.}". I put a breakpoint inside a method, and when the application stopes there, all the attributes of this object are null, and the application throws a NullPointerException.

2.
Remove annotations "ManagedBean" and "SessionsScoped" from Users.java, and declare the 2 managed beans in faces-config.xml:

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>currentUser</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>ro.telacad.model.Users</managed-bean-class>   
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>newUser</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>ro.telacad.model.Users</managed-bean-class>   
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

Of course, this time I use in login page and in welcome page "#{currentUser.}". This time, the NullPointerException is thrown in both cases (login and sign up).

The file faces-config.xml is loaded. I tested this by creating a class TempBean.java with 1 attribute and 1 method, declaring a managed bean of this class in faces-config.xml and use this in a h:form. It worked.

Comment: Who ever is filling the fields in the bean is probably referring to a bean named `users`? Why do you need this kind of pattern?

Comment: If spring can be ignored, why did you add it or the tag? And having both a spring and a jsf annotation on a class is bad practice (causes problems even)

Comment: It's a personal application, where I want to learn borh JSF and Spring. So I am beginner with both of them.

Comment: It would be prefarable to learn using CDI in this case.

Comment: You might want to create two new classes which `extend Users` class. Both of them can be made managed beans of arbitrary scope and name using annotations. Additionally both can have their own @PostConstruct method for initializing their state.

Comment: And please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging @Selaron: Switching to CDI and using producers is another option. No need to extend then.

Comment: @Kukeltje thank you, I'm still not that deeply in the CDI stuff. Will look into it   :D

Answer (score 0):

I extended "Users" class, exactly like Selaron said in the comment. It works fine. But I think it is not a good idea to do this in a real application, but for the moment I don't have any better idea.

Comment: and maybe (but I would not go there since it is deprecated) the JSF `@ManagedProperty` works to